# I facing the error 'Error - 0:error...' whene i click on magento2 category listing

Tags: iphone, safari, onclick, categories, magento2

Whene i am clicking on category listing then some time this error is showing some one can help me to resolve it?
This issue is occure only on iphone not in desktop or android device.
My website is in magento 2.3.1.
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/byzMz.jpg

Comment: I upvoted your question because I think you've probably done the same research I have. You've made note that it occurs only on iPhone for you; I will note that it only occurs on Firefox for me (on my website). Research on google yields nothing related except your post -- everything else I see is bogus sites and porn sites which somehow have found a way to come up and make us think the search term is in their site. I don't click on those. I'll share anything I find here.